# Alphanumeric sorting in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, optimization, logic

How can we do alphanumeric sorting in typescript to get the following series?
**['1_11', '1_10', '1_9'...'1_1','1_0']**

Should it be split and sorted separately?

Comment: Hello and welcome. What is the expected output ?

Comment: @KBell Hi, the expected output is as shown above-must be sorted in descending order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will sort the array:

```
this.array = this.array.sort((a, b) => {
  return +a.replace('_', '') > +b.replace('_', '') ? -1 : a === b ? 0 : 1
})
```

Comment: This is of course shorter, but much less optimal than the solution above, since these string replacements here will be done for each single comparison, i.e. multiple times per value rather than just once before and after the sort step...

Answer (score 3):

If you want full control over the sort order of the delimited values, you'll not be able to avoid splitting the values first. The solution below uses the `compare2By()` higher-order function to let you choose the sort key order and ascending/descending ordering per key.

(UPDATED to support key specific sort orders)

```
type Comparator<T> = (a: T, b: T) => number;

function compareAsc<T>(a: T, b: T) {
  return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
}

function compareDesc<T>(a: T, b: T) {
  return a < b ? 1 : a > b ? -1 : 0;
}

function compare2By<T extends any[]>(
    x = 0,
    y = 1,
    cmpX: Comparator<T[0]> = compareAsc,
    cmpY: Comparator<T[1]> = compareAsc
) {
  return (a: T, b: T) =>
    cmpX(a[x], b[x]) || cmpY(a[y], b[y]);
}

function sortDelimited(src: string[], sortFn: Comparator<number[]>, del = "_") {
  return src
    .map((x) => x.split(del))
    // optional int coercion, not sure if needed for OP
    .map((x) => x.map((y) => parseInt(y)))
    .sort(sortFn)
    .map((x) => x.join(del));
}

console.log(
    JSON.stringify(sortDelimited(
        ['1_11', '1_10', '1_9', '1_1', '1_0'],
        // UPDATED: use total descending order
        // for both first and second sort key
        compare2By(0, 1, compareDesc, compareDesc)
    ))
)

// ["1_11","1_10","1_9","1_1","1_0"]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAQwE7OHVAeAKgPigF4oAKZALilwBooAjK3ASmMIDsBXBeiVAbgBQggGad2AY2ABLOOygTEKVBACCAZwl585JnUbVWAb0FQoK4J1TzkUbAygB+KAFoAjFCq3C9J1A9UAAxCAL7CYpIycgpKaBAAIhCa2rrU+kzGpuYQltZQtva+zgH5UD5+7p5QwYJhouJSsvKKSHEATABCIHhQEAAewBDsACbq+ewgANoAujpZZn3E1TTzUCBLbitmZhJIABpU8K3omDi4k4GzSy3Kappb27tgAJqHsSdYeJNuVyQ3cRoJIJMmYLFZ5KlaAwMmxVk89uRJn1pvokdNWAAfDEKJDPREgFEMSYE5ihcINKLydRYYCJAA20gQ0kGw1I6lQEio6mAqGk7AA5jM6NTUMAAGLsN7HDCfLg8PgzfB0YYQOlLABEAH11SDsrkqRzVgA6BDIMCkUh9VhEQh9I3qMAM4CkFV05jMVYAek9UDgYEpyDVfOAMT4EiadHYcBD6is0GkIig7AgEBVwygIiwUAA8gAFY2m82W622k1mi0gEtQZTqCAASXYzsr7uNIudbYlHu2UDLRatbCgdoAVnA+S7Ve6yYJFOxqXSIEa6XB+aRVgApADK2YAcvaeXz+QmQGyafTGczU6vu93JgByNyatxuW90e+PwIvqBvgCcn7fz9fB8PxRVZu29KAAFVc3iVRcAAUXiKhOFrKBMGAQMoBVTQhmGA9fVQFVUFA7ZwMzVAGGjAALDNpFQblxnTWsZ0YmkoAAawgEBiJ2d4IE6Y9AjoTYYmOBIkgkOh-hURJNC7bYWw9QRwMmdUHyfdUaFU98NK078dLU-TNUCdVpiAA)

Comment: Small tip - `compareDesc` is trivially derivable from `compareAsc` by invoking it and negating the result - `compareDesc = (a, b) => compareAsc(a, b) * -1`. You can also make a higher order helper `reverse = f => (a, b) => f(a, b) * -1` which makes `comparesDesc = reverse(compareAsc)` :P

Comment: @VLAZ theoretically yes, but then again your `reverse()` would only have this one single use case (i.e. reversing `compareAsc`) so arguably much of an improvement (esp. if it incurs an additional fn call for each single comparison, just to flip the sign). seems a bit nitpicky... :)

Comment: You can have other comparators, however. For example if you want case insensitive comparison, you should do `caseInsensitiveAsc = new Intl.Collator().compare`. in which case you can derive the reverse again, instead of writing another comparator. It means that if you change it to ignore diacretics, you automatically get the same functionality in the reverse. You can also do sorting by multiple fields, for example which will require another comparator for it. Or comparator for other items that don't obey `<` and `>`. Although I suppose you could also just use a `flip` to swap comaprison.

Comment: @VLAD agree with all of that, but it's just somewhat out-of-scope of what was asked here, no? :) Anyway, same page, all good!